# Re-finding a component with Enzyme still doesn't return what should be the correct prop value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have these two components. One is a modal and another is a button the should open that modal (it is opened by passing `true` to its `isOpen` prop.

The modal starts of with isOpen being `false`, then when the button is clicked, it changes that state to true.
When compiling it woks just fine as intended. In my tests though, it keeps returning `false` as the value of `isOpen` even after clicking the button.

These are my two components and the state he handles them:

```
  const [isManagePaymentSourceShowing, setIsManagePaymentSourceShowing] = useState(false);

  <ManageSubscriptionModal
   isOpen={isManageSubscriptionShowing}
   onClickX={closeManageSubscriptionModals}
   onClickCancelSubscription={() => setIsSignInAgainShowing(true)}
   data-test="amsp-manage-subscription-modal"
  />

  <TextCtaButton
   fontSize={["13px", "12px"]}
   fontWeight="600"
   textTransform="uppercase"
   onClick={() => {
   setIsManagePaymentSourceShowing(true);
   console.log("Button was clicked ".repeat(100));
   }}
   data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-button"
   >
      manage payment source
   </TextCtaButton>
```

I've added that console log too and I see that the button does get clicked in the test.

This is the test I am trying to run:

```
const setup = (userSubscription = userSubscriptionFixture()) => {
  return mount(
    <Wrapper>
      <AccountManagementSubscriptionPresentational
        subscriptionProduct={undefined}
        userSubscription={userSubscription}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

describe("Check modal display toggles work", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let modal;
  let updatedModal;
  let openButton;
  let openFunction;

  test("<ManagePaymentSourceModal>", () => {
    wrapper = setup();
    modal = wrapper.find(`[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-modal"]`);
    openButton = wrapper.find(
      `[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-button"]`
    );
    openFunction = openButton.prop("onClick") as () => void;

    expect(modal.prop("isOpen")).toBeFalsy();
    openFunction();
    updatedModal = wrapper.find(
      `[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-modal"]`
    );
    expect(updatedModal.prop("isOpen")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

That last expect always fails saying it expected true and got false instead.

EDIT: I've tried tuning the test into an async function thing mabe it's the state change that just takes too long, but that didn't work either. This is how I've tried it:

```
  test("<ManagePaymentSourceModal>", async () => {
    wrapper = setup();
    modal = wrapper.find(`[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-modal"]`);
    openFunction = wrapper
      .find(`[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-button"]`)
      .prop("onClick") as () => void;

    expect(modal.prop("isOpen")).toBe(false);
    await openFunction();
    updatedModal = wrapper.find(
      `[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-modal"]`
    );
    expect(updatedModal.prop("isOpen")).toBe(true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my test to th following (`invoke` instead of `prop`) has solved my issue

```
openFunction = wrapper
  .find(`[data-test="amsp-manage-payment-source-button"]`)
  .invoke("onClick") as () => void;
```